# MySQL, get all rows describing one product from table 1, by their references in table 2

Tags: mysql

I need to find all attributes & image(s) for a product.
Every product is marked as such in the column `type` in Table 1.
The attributes are also defined in Table 1, each attribute on a seperate row.

This is a simplified version of the table structures:

```
Table 1:
id | type     | value   | url
1  | product  | T-shirt |    
2  | image    |         | http://www......
........
15 | size     | XXL     | 
........
18 | color    | blue    |

Table 2:
id | ref_id | link_id   
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 2
3  | 1      | 15
4  | 1      | 18
```

The relationship between a product and its attributes is defined in Table 2:
- `ref_id` matches the id in Table 1 for the product we want
- `link_id` holds an id (from Table 1) which is either the product itself or an attribute of the product

So in this example, `id` 1 in Table 1 has 4 occurences in Table 2 (`ref_id = 1`): the product row and 3 attribute rows (`image`, `size` & `color`)
They are referenced by the column `link_id` in Table 2.

I would like to solve this in 1 query if possible, but I am stuck at how to solve the 'back-reference'.
Once I have found a product's id in Table 1, I can get the `link_id`'s in Table 2 allright, but how do I use those again (in the same query) to get the rows from Table 1.

Is this at all possible in 1 query, or should I use 2 seperate queries for this?

UPDATE:
this is how far I have come:

```
SELECT      t1.id, t1.type, t1.value, t1.url,  
            t2.link_id
FROM        table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN   table_2 t2
ON          t1.id = t2.ref_id
WHERE       t1.type = 'product'
```

But after that I don't know how to construct the rest of the query based on the 'back-reference'.

Comment: Any query you have already tried?

Comment: See UPDATE in my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join back to table_1 again

```
SELECT      t1.id, t1.type, t1.value, t1.url,  
            t2.link_id, t1_attributes.type, t1_attributes.value
FROM        table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN   table_2 t2
ON          t1.id = t2.ref_id
LEFT JOIN   table_1 t1_attributes ON t2.link_id = t1_attributes.id
WHERE       t1.type = 'product'
```

This will get you 1 row for each attribute though. If you want a field for each type of attribute, you'll have to do a join for each one.

```
SELECT      t1.id, t1.type, t1.value, t1.url,  
            t2.link_id, t1_image.value, t1_size.value
FROM        table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN   table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.ref_id
LEFT JOIN   table_1 t1_image ON t2.link_id = t1_image.id
LEFT JOIN   table_1 t1_size ON t2.link_id = t1_size.id
WHERE       t1.type = 'product' AND t1_image.type = 'image' AND 
            t1_size.type = 'size'
```

Comment: Thanks so much rgvassar. The second solution works great :)